# Data parse from multiple rsyslog to logstash to elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk, rsyslog

I am new to ELK. I have deployed my ELK with this article.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-22-04

I skipped the nginx part and just used the rest process.

My goal is to transfer rsyslogs form multiple locations to Logstash to elasticsearch and want to see it on kibana.

But having issue and do not know how to archive this. Can some one please guide me here ?

Also when we send logs from rsyslog it includes multiple vhosts logs so how can we differentiate that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Also do no know how to create a grok filter patters. Does any one know how can i learn this Grok pattern thing.

Data parse from multiple rsyslog to logstash to elasticsearch